# How to convert a string representation of a type back to an instance of a type in Python?

Tags: python, type-conversion

I have a function than returns the type of an object as a string as follows:

```py
>>> f(list())
"<class 'list'>"
```

How can I convert the output back to an instance of `type` ?

I have tried locate and eval and they return nothing. I've also read that eval() is unsafe.

Edit:
You can assume that `f` is defined as follows:

```py
def f(t):
    return repr(type(t))
```

Comment: Can you share the function?

Comment: Can't you modify that function to make it return something reasonable? Or is your real use case somehow different and more complicated?

Comment: I didn't think it was relevant, that's why I didn't include it. I've edited my question.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille My real use case is different and I'd rather not modify it because other functionalities depend on it as it is.

Comment: Maybe you should? Having the code depend on a textual representation seems like a strange idea - but maybe there's a very good reason to do so in your code, and I'd be interested in knowing which as I fail to find one. Though the repr of basic types probably never will change, I don't think that there's any guarantee they won't in future versions, and all this looks a bit fragile...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a reliable way to do this. You could do this super unsafe function for some types: `def g(rt): return eval(rt.split("'")[1])`. But this raises a `NameError` for imported types depending on what names you bound to imported modules e.g. `g("numpy.ndarray")` if `numpy` was bound to the name `np`.

You could instead store types mapped to their string representations in a dictionary for retrieving the type later, or you could rewrite your code to store the types and make the strings only when needed.